# TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object -- mimetypes.guess_type

Tags: python, mime-types

I am trying to detect the mimetype of a file stored in a mongodb database using pathfs. I am using "mimetypes" to do this, I try to pass the file as bytes but get the error `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

My code:

```
location = cur_post['file']
file_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(fs.get(location).read())
print(file_mimetype)
return send_file(BytesIO(fs.get(location).read()), mimetype=file_mimetype, as_attachment=False, attachment_filename=(str(random.randint(10000000,99999999)) + '.pdf'))
```

I have also tried `mimetypes.guess_type(io.BytesIO(fs.get(location).read()))` and got a similar error

Comment: `mimetypes` guesses the mime type off the file extension using the filename, not by reading magic bytes from the file contents. Use a different library like [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the underlying code and the assets that you're using, I can only make an educated guess that you likely need to decode your bytes object into a string.

Something along the lines of:

```
 file_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(fs.get(location).read().decode())
```

But as has already been mentioned, you may not have the appropriate tool for the job. For file identification I usually see the [filetype](https://github.com/h2non/filetype.py) library used more often than anything else.

```
import filetype

with open('grail.png', 'rb') as fh: grail = fh.read()
type(grail) # bytes
best_guess = filetype.guess(grail)
print(best_guess.mime)  # 'image/png'
```